# Override CMFCLinkCtrl click behaviour

Tags: visual-c++, hyperlink, mfc

I have a situation where I want to add a `CMFCLinkCtrl` to a dialog. But I want it to work like a button , so when I click the link I can show a dialog.

Eventually this link control will be on a panel in a status bar control. For testing I am just creating a dialog project and dragging a link control onto it.

In the IDE it listed `BN_CLICKED` but it does not appear to fire.

[image]

All I can see is the debug output:

> atlTraceGeneral - Can't open URL: MfcLink1

I tried declaring my own class, derived from `CMFCLinkCtrl` and adding this `protected` method:

```
BOOL CMyMFCLinkCtrl::OnClicked()
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Hi");

    return 0;
}
```

Since I saw it in the MFC sources but this is also not intercepted.

Comment: Did you include something like this in the message map of your derived class?`ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX(BN_CLICKED, &CMyMFCLinkCtrl::OnClicked)` ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky That was it! Adding that line causing my handler to intercept. Thank you. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked) notifications are always sent to the control's parent. To be able to handle the message in the control its parent needs to opt in to [message reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/handling-reflected-messages). It is a feature that allows notifications to be handled in either the child control window or the parent window, or in both.

To enable message reflection, the parent's message map must contain one of `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT()` or `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX()`, e.g., `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX(BN_CLICKED, &CMyMFCLinkCtrl::OnClicked)`. This ensures the `BN_CLICKED` message is routed through the control's message handler.

To handle the button click in the parent window it needs to register a callback through its message map. An [`ON_COMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc#on_command) entry will do, e.g., `ON_COMMAND(IDC_MY_BUTTON, &MyDialog::OnMyCommand)`, where `IDC_MY_BUTTON` is the control ID of the button and `OnMyCommand()` the designated message handler (taking no arguments and returning `void`).

Handling a control notification in the control's parent window follows standard message routing. It works with and without message reflection.

Comment: I found that if I put the `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX` in the control and a `ON_COMMAND` in the parent it works.

Comment: All I know is that I can't use a `CMFCLinkCtrl` and override the "click" in the parent for custom behaviour unless I do the steps I have stated.